# Run .slideDown() after trigger('click');

Tags: jquery, triggers

On page load I need to simulate a click on the  tag and then, when it´s clicked I want to slideDown(); the #commenter-info.

So what I'm looking for is something like this:

```
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'true') {
        $(this).trigger("click", function() {
                       $(this).closest('form').find('#commenter-info').slideDown();
                    });
    }
```

If the id of the  is "true", click the link and then perform the slideDown();

The problem is that the "#commenter-info" is added on the click event and not present on pageload.

Comment: $(this).attr('id') will give you the element ID

Comment: What is the problem .??

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle or provide more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to proceed in two steps.

```
if ($(this).attr('id') == 'true') {

  // First set up the listener :

  $(this).bind("click", function() {
    $(this).closest('form').find('#commenter-info').slideDown();
  });

  // Then, fire the click event

  $(this).click();
}
```

Comment: I think that the problem is that this form is dynamically loaded oh the click event.. so it´s not present until after the click. Any ideas?

Comment: Which event is launched after the creation of the form ?

Comment: On click, the form is added.. and when the form is added I want to run "$(this).closest('form').find('#commenter-info').slideDown();"

Comment: You can't listen to an dom update, and as the form is generated AFTER  the click, you can't listen to it either.

Comment: You could try to plug into the form genration or a setTimeout (but the earth will collide itself). Could you tell me how the form is generated ?

Comment: Acctually you gave me an idea that solved the issue!.. the div was set to display:none with inline css.. I removed it and added it thru jquery which gave me better control of it! :) Big thanks!